# Docker run giving different result to docker build (trying to use 32bit image on 64bit host)

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm trying to use a 32-bit docker image (from https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/protomouse/debian-i386/) on my 64-bit machine and am getting a result I wasn't expecting.

First up, I'm using boot2docker and have v1.5.0 of the boot2docker image (the current version). My machine is Darwin x86_64.

Once docker is all set up:

```
$> docker pull protomouse/debian-i386:wheezy
$> docker run protomouse/debian-i386:wheezy uname -a
Linux c16621f70b0d 3.18.5-tinycore64 #1 SMP Sun Feb 1 06:02:30 UTC 2015 i686 GNU/Linux
```

The `i686` is looking very promising in the result from `uname -a`...
But when I go to making a dockerfile to extend the image, I get a different result. My dockerfile:

```
$> cat Dockerfile
FROM protomouse/debian-i386:wheezy

RUN uname -a
```

I build this with:

```
$> docker build  --no-cache . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.032 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM protomouse/debian-i386:wheezy
 ---> 819840964f5f
Step 1 : RUN uname -a
 ---> Running in defe4361f7db
Linux 5eda7c5eb292 3.18.5-tinycore64 #1 SMP Sun Feb 1 06:02:30 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 ---> 65df78215ee1
Removing intermediate container defe4361f7db
Successfully built 65df78215ee1
```

Notice that the result of `uname -a` is now telling me I have x86_64.

I'm fairly new to docker, so suspect I have fundamentally mis-understood the difference between the two operations, but I'd really appreciate it if anybody could shed any light on the matter.

Comment: you should read https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/611

Comment: extract from the prvious link --> uname will always tell you 64 bits. Look at e.g. "file /bin/sh" to see the real arch of the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea what is different between the two setups though? Why does one report differently to the other?